# Wordpress manual restore not completely successful

Tags: backup

I have restore my blog after around 4 years. I had a backup of both the database and wordpress files. I restore the database and wordpress files. The only manual modification I did is that I changed every occurrence of the site url in the raw mysql dump to the `http://172.105.4.68` that is where my blog is currently. Everything worked properly except that node of the post and page content is being shown. When I login as the administrator, I can see the content but when I view the post or page, i cannot see the content. For example, on this [post](http://172.105.4.68/?p=1622), I can see the post title and tags but not the content. Also, I have noticed, even if I create a new page or post, I can't still see the content. Any reason this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems strange since you can see the content in the backend but not able to see it in the frontend. So here are a few suggestions.

1. Try to save the permalink again? And try to clear the cache too.
2. Try to change the theme to any other basic theme available.

Also when I tried to go to http://172.105.4.68/about-me , it's giving me internal server error.

Comment: the about-me was a custom link in the menu that i removed and replaced by its page.

Comment: I did both but it didn't work

Comment: I have noticed, even if I create a new post, I can't still the content

Comment: @Noor Please try to deactivate all the plugins and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: amazingly, it does :)